# How do I append to an existing array list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this dictionary :

```
{ "hex" : [] }
```

I want to be able to run a method where I can enter a value that will be appended into that list, however, I want to save the memory of that list so that if I were to run the method twice I would get two entries.

So for example method(1), method(2) will return:

```
{ "hex" : [1,2] }
```

This is the code I have:

```
def getMultiHex(file, getHexCode):
hexDict = {}
with open(file, 'r') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)

for index, element in enumerate(data):
    hex_iter = iter(element.values())
    hex_code = next(hex_iter)
    if getHexCode == hex_code:
        elem = element['hex']
        hexDict['hex'] = []
        hexDict['hex'].append(elem)

with open('Multihex.json', 'w') as w:
    databox = json.dump(hexDict, w)
return hexDict`
```

Now this works but everytime I run the method to enter a differnt value, the dictionary is overwritten. I understand that I initialise a new dictionary every time the method is executed but what work arounds do I have?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One option is to build `hexDict` from a file and save it after every manipulation.

Comment: Your example cannot be run without the input file. Please learn how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also there is a problem with the code formatting.

Comment: You can pass the dictionary into the method, so the calling code can pass it in on each call and you don't create a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you recreate the list every time you add an element (in your code: `hexDict['hex'] = []`), old values will obviously be overwritten. You can either pre-define the dict values like

```
    data = dict(some_key=[])
    
    for x in new_data:
        data["some_key"].append(x)
```

or you could just use a `defaultdict`:

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    data = defaultdict(list)
    
    for x in new_data:
        data["some_key"].append(x)  # the list will be created if the key doesn't exist
```

If you want to add data to the same dict with multiple calls of your outer function, you can create the dict before the first call and pass it to all calls, appending data each time:

```
    def add_data(data, new_data):
        for x in new_data:
            data["some_key"].append(x)

    data = defaultdict(list)

    add_data(data, [1, 2])
    add_data(data, [3, 4])
```